# Windows Themes ButtonChrome Border

Tags: wpf, button, controls

I have created my own button based on icrosoft_Windows_Themes2:ButtonChrome. I want to get rid of the default border and i've tried setting it to null or transparent but still i get a white border.

Here's my markup:

```
<Microsoft_Windows_Themes2:ButtonChrome x:Name="ibAero" Visibility="Collapsed" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" RoundCorners="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" OverridesDefaultStyle="True">
    <Border x:Name="bd" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=BorderBrush}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8,1,5,1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=Text}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=TextForeground}" Margin="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=TextMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Microsoft_Windows_Themes2:ButtonChrome>
```

EDIT:

Ok. I've changed the markup like this:

```
<Border x:Name="ibAero" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ibAeroPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8,1,5,1">
        <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=Image}" Width="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=ImageWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=ImageHeight}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=Text}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=TextForeground}" Margin="{Binding ElementName=IB, Path=TextMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

How do i set the default style in my usercontrol?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem is posted by Meleak in this link: [How to remove ButtonChrome border (when defining the template of a border)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553692/how-to-remove-buttonchrome-border-when-defining-the-template-of-a-border)

The reason you get that white border is because it is added IN CODE in the ButtonChrome control. There is NO WAY to achieve the solution to this with templating. The only way to remove the border is write your own version of the control.

I googled this issue and found numerous answers by people offering template "solutions". None of them will ever possibly work as suggested.

Add Meleak's modified ButtonChrome.cs control to your library of customized WPF controls (ComboBox with disabled F4 key being another in my personal inventory) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not including the Button Chrome in your template.  It would require extra work if you want to recreate some of the nice effects it provides on mouseover and pressed, but it will get rid of the border.

Comment: How do i set the default style in my usercontrol?