# WPF - White border in win 7

Tags: wpf

I have the following code for a button:

```
<Button Content="Logoff" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
        Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

In my current OS Win 7 i still get a white border. How can i remove this?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with coding style, I removed the tag

Answer (score 0):

The white border appears because of the default chrome of the button.Chrome classes are theme specific.You can completely customize it according to your liking or else you can completely delete the chrome of the button control.Check the below posts for more

[How to remove ButtonChrome border (when defining the template of a border)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553692/how-to-remove-buttonchrome-border-when-defining-the-template-of-a-border/4554404#4554404)

[Get rid of button border in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2899948/217880)

[How do you completely remove the button border in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/995757/217880)