# hide or remove border of wpf button in C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, c#-3.0

I have a stackpanel named "mystack" in my xaml file and I am adding buttons in it dynamically from the .cs file and want to remove the border of buttons in C# .cs file

what I really want is to populate this stackpanel with the buttons coming from a list of string
thanks in advance

xaml:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="227" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2"    
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="530">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel Name="mystack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="520"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

.cs:

```
     public List<String> Schools()
    {

        List<String> l = new List<string>();
        l.Add("SST");
        l.Add("SBE");
        l.Add("SSH");

        return l;

    }
```

Comment: That's not the right way to create a UI. You're not supposed to create / manipulate UI elements in code. Post a screenshot of what you need and we can give you a proper way to implement it in XAML.

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> what I really want is to populate this stackpanel with the buttons
>   coming from a list of string

That's called a `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Button Content="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                   <!-- Whatever other customizations to the button -->
        </DataTemplate
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items {get;set;}

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservablecCollection<string>();
        Items.Add("String1");
        Items.Add("String2");
        Items.Add("String3");
    }
}
```

You need to learn the MVVM pattern.

Comment: where the class viewmoel will be set in the binding?

Comment: below the `InitializeComponent()` you need to add `DataContext = new ViewModel()`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with HighCore, you generally do not want to manipulate the UI elements in your code.

To remove the `Border` of the buttons you can set a Button's `BorderThickness` property to "0" in Xaml or to `new Thickness(0)` in the code-behind.

i.e.

```
myButton.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
```

EDIT:

Okay, I noticed your updated question.  I would create a property that stores your list of schools and bind to it in a way similar to this:

```
public List<string> Schools 
{ 
    get { return _schools; }
    set { _schools = value; } 
}
```

Somewhere you need to set the `DataContext` of the control to your class containing the `Schools` property.  If you are dynamically updating the list of Schools you'll need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) so the UI knows when to update. And then your Xaml would look something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Schools}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Button Content="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl>
```

Comment: button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0) in the code not working

Comment: ItemsSource="Schools"....is this setting the class from where the data will come?

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify.  If setting the Thickness to 0 does not work, then you'll probably need to modify the controltemplate of the button and remove the border: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx

Comment: ItemsSource="Schools"....is this setting the class from where the data will come?

Answer (score 0):

### The fast Fix:

What I had to do to effectively `hide` the button border - and due to the button control template I believe which utilizes and changes Button border (i.e. **even if you remove it it'd draw it on some trigger I believe**)...

...was to set `BorderBrush="Transparent"` as well (I always do `BorderThickness` as well but I'm guessing it's not needed - only for visual/layout look'n'feel)

i.e. setting `thickness` alone is not enough.

> I'm really not sure that's the bets way to do it, or actually I'm
>   quite sure there must be something smarter - but I always end up with
>   that.

### The Right Way:

> Proper way - and recommended - is to write your own Button template -
>   based on the Microsoft official one - or `base` it on it - and do what
>   you need w/o borders.

For the code behind/C#:

> You really don't need that as per your changed question - do what others suggested already

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove button's border like: `btn.BorderThicknes=new Thickness(0);`

See this: [Removing button's border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553692/how-to-remove-buttonchrome-border-when-defining-the-template-of-a-border)

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is :

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```